# classification using sklearn RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit RandomForestClassifier to classify unbalanced data. The target class data is either '1' or '0' (99% of the values are 0).

I'd like to assign a weight. how can I do that.

I found in documenation:

> sample_weight : array-like, shape = [n_samples] or None
>
> Sample weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted. Splits
>   that would create child nodes with net zero or negative weight are
>   ignored while searching for a split in each node. In the case of
>   classification, splits are also ignored if they would result in any
>   single class carrying a negative weight in either child node.

I need to increase the influence of '1'

Is this the way I should do it:

```
s_weight = np.array([100 if i == 1 else 1 for i in y_train])
```

or this way :

```
s_weight = y_train[:, 1:100].T.ravel()
```

.

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=s_weights)
```

As I didn't get the expected results, Can anyone confirm please ?

Comment: The first is the way to go. You may want to try 100 instead of 5, reflecting the inverse frequency (This is a heuristic, no theory dictating this value). Out of curiosity: How many true targets / data points do you have available?

Comment: I have 50K item ! Should I use it this way : s_weight = y_train[:, 1:100].T.ravel()

Comment: The first option, not the second option.

Comment: Should I do it this way: s_weight = np.array([100 if i == 1 else 1 for i in y_train]) or this way: s_weight = np.array([100 if i == 1 else 0 for i in y_train]) as in the first, I am changing 0 to 1 and 1 to 100.

Comment: In most estimators with sample weights, specifying 0 as a sample weight is like omitting the sample. I don't think that this is what you want.

Comment: so s_weight = np.array([100 if i == 1 else 1 for i in y_train])  this is the perfect choice, right !

Comment: @eickenberg : I found two different results with the both statements. Which one should I use: s_weight = np.array([100 if i == 1 else 1 for i in y_train]) or s_weight = np.array([100 if i == 1 else 0 for i in y_train])

Answer (score 1):

Technically

```
s_weight = np.array([100 if i == 1 else 1 for i in y_train])
```

is correct, although weighting in RF is not so simple as in case of for example SVM. You will have to cross validate in order to find best weighting (which will be probably much smaller than `100`).

Comment: It is not as simple for SVM either. Cross validated sample weights can be smaller or larger than the inverse frequency.

Comment: not as simple **to interpret** as in case of SVM was what I meant.